# Brake IOS tabbed bar navigation into several storyboards

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I am developing an IOS app using a tabbed view controller as root controller. Basically the tabbed bar manages the presentation of the different app modules.
I would like to brake down my storyboard into several storyboards one for each tab so to brake it down in size and begin more manageable.

I cannot find any tutorial or suggestion on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `xib` files via Xcode and create your view controllers with those. You still have to reference and lay out your custom classes in the storyboard file, but you can manage all the details in the separate xib files.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.
I have created only the first tab via storyboard and then added new storyboard and tabs when the first controller is created.

In viewDidLoad:

```
NSMutableArray *tabs = (NSMutableArray *)[self.tabBarController viewControllers];

[tabs addObjectsFromArray:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tab1, tab2, tab3, nil]];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tabs];
```

Any tab is generated like this:

```
UIStoryboard *board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"FeedbacksStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = [board instantiateInitialViewController];
UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Feedback" image:nil tag:0];
controller.tabBarItem = theItem;
```

This was a good compromise. I can now load different storyboard and my app looks modular even in interface builder